# ActionController::UnknownFormat error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'd like to call a JavaScript function from a method in a controller the function is written in a file with the name of the method create.js.erb but error ActionController::UnknownFormat
arises.I don't know what is the problem?

app/views/favorite_places/create.js.erb

```
function my_function()
{
    swal("Place is not saved in google maps!", "Please move the marker to the desired location and add its name");
}
```

app/controllers/favorite_places_controler

```
def create
        #Checks if the current user have this favorite place already ,it renders Favorite Place already exists
        if current_user.favorite_places.include?(FavoritePlace.find_by(:name => favorite_place_params[:name]))
          id=FavoritePlace.find_by(:name => favorite_place_params[:name]).id
          redirect_to favorite_places_path , notice: 'Favorite place already exists'
        else
         #Checks if the favorite Place exists in the database it finds the place puts it in the variable favorite place
          if FavoritePlace.exists?(:name => favorite_place_params[:name])
            @favorite_place = FavoritePlace.find_by(:name => favorite_place_params[:name])
         #Or it  will create a new one with the allowed parameters only.  
          else
            @favorite_place = FavoritePlace.new(favorite_place_params)
            @favorite_place.save
          end
          id=@favorite_place.id
          #It assigns the favorite place to the user.
          UserFavoritePlace.add_favorite_place(current_user,@favorite_place) 
          redirect_to favorite_places_path , notice: 'Favorite place was successfully added.'
          respond_to do |format|
            format.js { render :js => "my_function();" }
          end
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a redirect_to before the respond_to block, which is wrong - the redirect_to should be in a format.html block inside the respond_to block.

Your unknown format error could be caused by the controller trying to handle and html request, which you don't handle inside the respond_to block.  Try changing this

```
      redirect_to favorite_places_path , notice: 'Favorite place was successfully added.'
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :js => "my_function();" }
      end
```

to this

```
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to favorite_places_path , notice: 'Favorite place was successfully added.' }
        format.js { render :js => "my_function();" }
      end
```

Comment: I have tried this the error disappeared but the function didn't run (The javascript didn't run) @Max Williams

Comment: It sounds like you are calling the action with an html request.

Comment: I can't understand,what is the problem then?

Comment: If you call it with an html request, it will run the html block in respond_to.  If you call it with a js request, it will run the js block in respond_to.  It sounds like you are calling it with an html request but expecting it to run the js block.

Comment: How to call it with js request ? @Max Williams